# Why does using salted hash on python and php give me different results?

Tags: python, php, sha1, cryptographic-hash-function

I ran into a problem in translating code from PHP to Python.
Initially, there is a PHP code that creates a salted hash of a password with verification, and this code works fine and performs its functions.
But I had a need to transfer this code to python. However, the resulting final hash does not match the one obtained on PHP.
Help me please.

**Here is the PHP code that works fine:**

```
<?php
$username = 'test';
$password = '1234';
$salt = '5CD6A52E4F7046241C1607233395461D69D8C21709DD661FA1E9A24C8DF39647';

$g = gmp_init(7);
$N = gmp_init('894B645E89E1535BBDAD5B8B290650530801B18EBFBF5E8FAB3C82872A3E9BB7', 16);

$h1 = sha1(strtoupper($username . ':' . $password), TRUE);
$h2 = sha1($salt . $h1, TRUE);
$h2 = gmp_import($h2, 1, GMP_LSW_FIRST);

// g^h2 mod N
$verifier = gmp_powm($g, $h2, $N);

// convert back to a byte array (little-endian)
$verifier = gmp_export($verifier, 1, GMP_LSW_FIRST);

// pad to 32 bytes, remember that zeros go on the end in little-endian!
$verifier = str_pad($verifier, 32, chr(0), STR_PAD_RIGHT);

ECHO 'Verifier FINAL ', $verifier;
?>
```

**Here's the python code I'm stuck on that doesn't produce the correct hash:**

```
import hashlib
import secrets
import sys

USERNAME = 'test'
PASSWORD = '1234'
salt = '5CD6A52E4F7046241C1607233395461D69D8C21709DD661FA1E9A24C8DF39647'

g = 7
N = '894B645E89E1535BBDAD5B8B290650530801B18EBFBF5E8FAB3C82872A3E9BB7'

N = int('{0:08b}'.format(int(N, 16)), 2)

h1 = str(hashlib.sha1(str((USERNAME + ':' + PASSWORD).upper()).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest())
h2 = str(hashlib.sha1(str(salt + h1).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest())
h2 = int('{0:08b}'.format(int(h2, 16)), 2)

verifier = pow(g, h2, N)
verifier = format(verifier, "x").upper()
verifier = verifier.ljust(64, '0')

print('Verifier FINAL : ', verifier)
print('Verifier should be: E08847151054CB20CCD00A546A85D9A4E6EB882EDAB678DD8C68BB28DA22C678')
```

Comment: Hashing doesn't necessarily produce the same hash each time for the same given input. The important thing will be whether you can verify the original value correctly against the hash or not - like when you have to check a password at login. P.s. why is the php version inventing its own routine and not just using password_hash()? Especially since sha1 is not considered secure anymore.

Comment: Such a scheme for generating a hash in the trinity core project of the game server wow 335a.
This PHP code works great and creates salt-verifier pairs that allow you to log into the game.
I'm trying to create a script in python that can also generate salt-verifier pairs that would work on the server. Therefore, I ask for help to find an error or correct the code so that it works.

Comment: Well have you checked whether the results would work? The only error you've reported is that it doesn't seem to produce the same result...but hashing the same value twice is not guaranteed to produce the same result anyway.

Comment: I have tested a couple of pair salt-verifier that are used with PHP and python many times.
PHP pairs always works, but python does not pass verification.
Due to the fact that I deliberately made the salt constant to facilitate the search for stages, it turns out that the wrong hash is obtained.
Perhaps I made a mistake when translating the logic of the PHP script into python. Therefore, I ask the help of experienced programmers in resolving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

That's it, I managed to completely write a library for generating hashes and checking them.

```
import hashlib
import secrets

ACCOUNT_NAME = 'MyTestLogin'
ACCOUNT_PASSWORD = 'MyTestPassword'

def calculateSRP6Verifier(ACCOUNT_NAME: str, ACCOUNT_PASSWORD: str, SALT: str):
    g = int(7)
    N = int('894B645E89E1535BBDAD5B8B290650530801B18EBFBF5E8FAB3C82872A3E9BB7', 16)
    h1 = bytes.fromhex(hashlib.sha1(((ACCOUNT_NAME + ':' + ACCOUNT_PASSWORD).upper()).encode()).hexdigest())
    h2 = int(bytes.fromhex(hashlib.sha1(bytes.fromhex(SALT) + h1).hexdigest())[::-1].hex(), 16)
    VERIFIER = bytes.fromhex(format(pow(g, h2, N), 'X').ljust(64, '0'))[::-1].hex().upper()
    return VERIFIER

def getRegistrationData(ACCOUNT_NAME: str, ACCOUNT_PASSWORD: str):
    SALT = secrets.token_hex(32)
    VERIFIER = calculateSRP6Verifier(ACCOUNT_NAME, ACCOUNT_PASSWORD, SALT)
    return SALT.upper(), VERIFIER

def verifySRP6(ACCOUNT_NAME: str, ACCOUNT_PASSWORD: str, SALT: str, VERIFIER: str):
    g = int(7)
    N = int('894B645E89E1535BBDAD5B8B290650530801B18EBFBF5E8FAB3C82872A3E9BB7', 16)
    x = int(bytes.fromhex(hashlib.sha1(bytes.fromhex(SALT) + bytes.fromhex(hashlib.sha1(((ACCOUNT_NAME + ':' + ACCOUNT_PASSWORD).upper()).encode()).hexdigest())).hexdigest())[::-1].hex(), 16)
    VERIFIER = bytes.fromhex(format(pow(g, x, N), "X").ljust(64, '0'))[::-1].hex().upper()
    return VERIFIER
    
RESULT = getRegistrationData(ACCOUNT_NAME, ACCOUNT_PASSWORD)
print('This is SRP6 crypto library for Trinity Core 335a World of Warcraft server.')
print('')
print('Login   : ' + ACCOUNT_NAME)
print('Password: ' + ACCOUNT_PASSWORD)
print('')
print('salt    : ' + RESULT[0])
print('verifier: ' + RESULT[1])

# Note, that SALT and VERIFIER saved to the database as a binary string (not as hexadecimal, that returned from getRegistrationData() function)!
# Therefore, when inserting data into the MySQL database, you need to use such a query:
sql = "INSERT INTO account (username, salt, verifier, email) VALUES ('" + ACCOUNT_NAME.upper() + "', X'" + SALT + "', X'" + VERIFIER + "', '" + ACCOUNT_EMAIL.upper() + "')"



# This is simple example, how registration data is being verified.
#
#CODE - is return from verifySRP6() function
#VERIFIER and SALT - saved data from the MySQL database, from account table, converted from binary to hexadecimal string in upper() mode.
# MySQL query must be:
#    cursor.execute("SELECT salt FROM account WHERE username = '" + ACCOUNT_NAME.upper() + "'")
#    SALT = (cursor.fetchone()['salt']).hex().upper()
#    cursor.execute("SELECT verifier FROM account WHERE username = '" + ACCOUNT_NAME.upper() + "'")
#    VERIFIER = (cursor.fetchone()['verifier']).hex().upper()
#
#
#CODE = verifySRP6(ACCOUNT_NAME, ACCOUNT_PASSWORD, SALT, VERIFIER)
#print('check   :', CODE)
#if(VERIFIER == CODE):
#    print('Password is OK!')
#else:
#    print('Wrong password!')
```